# An efficient and free method of assembling a large number of Sanger sequencing reads?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, dna, dna-sequencing, sequence-analysis

I have a rather large number of Sanger Sequencing reads.

Is there a automated method in either Ugene or a similiar freeware that allows you to quickly assemble forward and reverse reads. Ideally something where the suffix of the filename will allow the software to automatically know which is the forward and reverse read.

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm not keen to do each sequence by hand in Bioedit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered SPAdes? It's a popular, state of the art assembler that should work with Sanger sequencing reads.

http://cab.spbu.ru/software/spades/

Answer (score 0):

What about the old [Phred, Phrad and Consed](http://www.phrap.org/phredphrapconsed.html) suite of programs?

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it would be appreciated if you could at least provide a link to these programs. As it is anyone would have to search.